# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. Please help me here

Tags: python, transactions, valueerror, tkinter-entry

the problem occurs in this line of code newAmountForAcc1 = int(currBalance) - int(amountToBeSent), i just want to get the amount to be transferred from one bank account to another, i have a Entry box for that (i used Tkinter), to get the amount i used .get() function. When I run the code it shows **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**. Here is the function

```
def transferMoney():
        newTransactionWindow = Tk()
        newTransactionWindow.title("Money Transfer")
        global secAcc
        secAcc=Entry(newTransactionWindow)
        secAcc.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30)
        global amount
        amount=Entry(newTransactionWindow)
        amount.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30)
    
        secAccLabel = Label(newTransactionWindow, text="Enter Receiver's Account number:")
        secAccLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30)
        amountLabel = Label(newTransactionWindow, text="Enter the amount to send:")
        amountLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30)
    
        amountToBeSent = amount.get()
    
        acc1 = deleteBox.get()
        acc2 = secAcc.get()
    
        statement1=f"select * from bank where ACC_NUM={acc1}"
        mycursor.execute(statement1)
        record = mycursor.fetchall()
        currBalance = 0
        for x in record:
            currBalance = x[7]
    
        newAmountForAcc1 = int(currBalance) - int(amountToBeSent)
        statement2=f"update bank set BALANCE = {newAmountForAcc1} where ACC_NUM={acc1}"
        mycursor.execute(statement2)
    
        newAmountForAcc2 = currBalance + amountToBeSent
        statement4 = f"update bank set BALANCE = {newAmountForAcc2} where ACC_NUM={acc2}"
        mycursor.execute(statement4)
        sendMoneyButton = Button(newTransactionWindow, text="Send Money", command=send)
        sendMoneyButton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, ipadx=50)
        mydb.commit()
        transactionCompletedWindow = Tk()
        transactionCompletedWindow.title("Transaction successful")
        transactionCompletedWindowLabel = Label(transactionCompletedWindow, text="Transaction completed successfully")
```

Comment: One of your values is an empty string and can't be converted to an int. Trace back where that value comes from!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of the variables contain a symbol that cannot be represented as a number. For example:

```
int('15a') # error
int('1.5') # error
int('1,5') # error
int('15') # nice
```

If variables literals should be fractional, then use `float()`:

```
float('1.5') # nice
float('15') # 15.0
# but
float('1,5') # error!
float('1,5'.replace(',', '.')) # fixes it
```